# Как в laravel Eloquent обращаться к столбцу, название которого состоит из нескольких слов

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

у меня есть бд, там есть таблица где одно из полей [ID языка], так вот в Eloquent вроде как надо обращаться к модели через такую конструкцию $model->Field. Но у меня название столбца состоит из двух слов, обращаться $model->[ID языка] нельзя.
Как тогда мне обратиться к этому полю?

Comment: `$model->{'ID языка'}` или есть же метод `toArray()`, для конвертации объекта в массив (`$model['ID языка']`)

Comment: Да точно, спасибо